# Issue generating an array

Tags: php, arrays

Any idea what is going on here, the array should look like so:

```
Array (
    [69] => Array (
        [KR] => 1
    )
    [70] => Array (
        [KR] => 2
    )
    [70] => Array (
        [LR] => 1
    )
    [71] => Array (
       [LR] => 1
    )
)
```

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    //Split the ID and Product into individual variable
    $tmp = explode("_",$key);
    $id = $tmp[0]; $product = $tmp[1];

    //Generate array's for each sale
    $sales[$id] = array($product => $value);
}
print_r($sales);
```

Here is the result it produces:

```
Array (
    [69] => Array (
        [KR] => 1
    )
    [70] => Array (
        [LR] => 1
    )
    [71] => Array (
        [LR] => 1
    )
)
```

Here is a quick table so you can see the actual collection of variables

```
69_KR   1
70_KR   2
70_LR   1
71_LR   1
```

Comment: The second assignment of a value to key 70 overwrites the first one.

Comment: I thought it would just append to it, how can I get it to do that?

Comment: The syntax to append to an array is to use empty square brackets, please see my suggested answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same sales id can occur multiple times then you shouldn't use it as an array key. The second time you have a sales id of 70, it overwrites the values of the first one.

There are many ways you can change this, here is one suggestion:

Before the foreach loop, create the empty array `$sales = array();` (you're probably already doing this)

If you don't mind an associative array (IMO they make code more readable/maintainable - think about someone else altering your code in 5 years and doing a var_dump on the $sales array), then try this instead inside the foreach:

`$sales[] = array("sales_id" => $id, "product" => $product, "value" => $value);`

You'll have to process the array slightly differently later, but a print_r or var_dump will be very easy to read indeed. (I also like to wrap print_r's in a `<pre>` tag for really nice array formatting when outputting to the browser.)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$sales[$id] = array($product => $value);
```

with

```
$sales[$id][$product] = $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

with

```
$sales[$id] = array($product => $value);
```

you are clobbering previous versions of $sales[$id]. you are losing data.

you need another data structure to store the values returned. like a list. which would look like

sales = list of each sale. 
then to access the each sale iterate of the length of the list.